# ZF2 Unlimited params for console route

Tags: php, console, routes, zend-framework2

I have such route:

```
'cronExec' => array(
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'exec [<commands>]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\Commands',
            'action' => 'exec'
        )
    )
),
```

This will catch:

- execCmd
- execCmd commandNameHere

But i would also like to catch second one with **unlimited** amount of params like:

- execCmd commandNameHere --x=y --a=b --c=1
- execCmd commandNameHere --param1=1 --param2=0

Or in any other way that will allow me to send **unlimited, unknown named params** to specified command but **onlywhen execCmd is set before it**

Answer (score 2):

```
'cronExec' => array(
    'type' => 'Catchall',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'exec',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\Commands',
            'action' => 'exec'
        )
    )
),
```

**UPDATE1**

or you could pass any parameters inside single parameter.

```
'cronExec' => array(
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'exec [--params=]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\Commands',
            'action' => 'exec'
        )
    )
),
```

call it like

```
php public/index.php exec --params="--any --other --params"
```

and in the controller parse `$this->params('params')` with `getopt` or whatever.

Comment: This will not work. Catchall seems to omit route. This mean it will catch anything you put into console request even if you don't set 'exec'. Both will be catch by your route: `exec commandName param1=a` and `commandName param1=a`. I need only the first option.

Comment: Make sure you put this rule first in the `['console']['router']['routes']` array. This way it will be matched only if any other didn't.

Comment: But I want to leave default zend action if I put wrong/non existing command. I could do it your way, but if I will do a mistake or want to see the list of available commands (for me it includes doctrine) it will jump into my 'exec' controller which is not intended to react on such things.

Comment: This is what I did just after I posted question, but I'm not glad with this solution. I don't understand why there is no such easy option for console routing. Big thnx for your effort!

Comment: And I don't understand why do you need so many parameters that can't be described in the route.

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem right now.  It should not be so hard to implement **echo**, right?  Basically, `writeLine(implode(" ", $args));` So how does one specify [repeatable_arg ...] in the route?